# How to run hive queries in Apache Zeppelin 0.7.2?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

As many of us know that Hive interpreter is not available by default in Apache Zeppelin version 0.7.2 on wards and many sites has recommended to use `jdbc` interpreter instead. I have included the hive properties in the `jdbc` interpreter to have my Hive interpreter running but get some error.

**Properties**

```
hive.driver     org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
hive.url    jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
hive.user   hive
```

**Error**

```
%jdbc(hive)
show databases

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.createConnectionPool(JDBCInterpreter.java:341)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getConnectionFromPool(JDBCInterpreter.java:352)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getConnection(JDBCInterpreter.java:372)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:565)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:692)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR
Took 0 sec. Last updated by anonymous at June 16 2017, 1:36:23 PM.
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about it but try installing the hive interpreter and test using the jdbc interpreter

Comment: Hi, did you add hive jars as a dependency in the `localhost:8080/#/interpreter` page?

Comment: I have tried all those methods.